# LSQR with matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use LSQR on matlab to solve a linear equations:
$$
aX + bY = Z
$$
so I form `[a b][X Y]' = Z` where `a, b` and `Z` are row vectors.

I am testing it on simulation i.e controlled data.

```
A = [a,b];
XY = lsqr(A,Z,1e-14,100);
```

However, I cant seem to get the right value for $X$ and $Y$. Is there any condition I should check for for my matrix A? The calculation converges at iteration number 2 with residual in the order of `e-14`. But the value is wrong.

Kelvin

Answer (score 1):

$Z$ must be a column vector. It actually gives an error message if you try to use a row vector, so the mistake might be that you used the wrong entry on `lsqr`.

Also, the LSQR method doesn't actually solve $Ax=b$, but minimizes $||Ax-b||$ and gives the solution $x$ with lower norm. The result you got is correct, you're probably just interpreting it the wrong way, for example, by checking if it solves $aX + bY = Z$.

Answer (score 0):

You did wrong, Z should be repeated. i.e

```
A = [a,b];
XY = lsqr(A,[Z;Z],1e-14,100);
```